# XA transaction not working with unixODBC on DB2

Tags: c++, db2, ibm-mq, unixodbc

I am trying to get XA transactions work using unixODBC driver for DB2 database and WMQ Manager using C++.
Default Auto Commit has been turned off

Following are the configurations:
UnixODBC => odbc.ini

```
Driver = DB2_DRIVER
Database = DBNAME
uid = username
pwd = password
```

WMQ => qm.ini

```
XAResourceManager: 
        Name=xa_name 
        SwitchFile=db2swit 
        XAOpenString=DBNAME,username,password,toc=p,hold_cursor=t 
        ThreadOfControl=PROCESS
```

Following are the steps that I follow in my program

```
1. Start transaction using MQBEGIN 
2. Database connectivity 
3. MQGET 
4. Insert in DB 
5. Disconnect DB 
6. End transaction with MQCMIT
```

After doing the mentioned steps message gets removed from MQ queue but not committed in database. Can anyone please tell me if I am missing some configuration here.

```
Versions of softwares used    
unixODBC => 2.3.2   
Websphere MQ => 7.1.0.0   
DB2 client => 9.7 fix pack 4
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tested with the IBM sample programs? Did they work or did they exhibit the same behavior?

Comment: IBM sample programs if I am not mistaken use embedded sql. We are facing issues with unixODBC and not embedded sql